# JS document.on for cached element

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I have code like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#element_1, #element_2", function() {
  alert("clicked")
})
```

Suppose I cached both `element_1` and `element_2`, then how would I write (if possible) the eventHandler?

```
element_1 = $("#element_1")
element_2 = $("#element_2")

// obviously below fails with a syntax error because an object has been passed rather than a string selector
$(document).on("click", element_1, element_2, function() {
  alert("clicked")
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.add()` to merge one or more jQuery objects into a single  jQuery object collection passed at second parameter to `.on()`

```js
var element_1 = $("#element_1");
var element_2 = $("#element_2");
var element_3 = $("#element_3");

$(document).on("click", element_1.add(element_2, element_3 /* element_N */)
 , function(e) {
  alert(e.target.id + " clicked")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="element_1">element 1</div>
<div id="element_2">element 2</div>
<div id="element_3">element 3</div>
```